# Why is the value of my checkbox always saved as 0 in the production environment?

Tags: cakephp

I have a checkbox in cakephp 3.6

```
<div class="input checkbox required link-policy">
    <input type="hidden" name="newsletter" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="1">
</div>
```

Then in my controller I access the post value and I save it to a contacts table

`$newContact->newsletter = $this->request->getData()['newsletter'];
  $contactsTable->save($newContact);`

I have a table with a column defined like `TINYINT` where I want to store if the customer has accepted to receive newsletter or not with a 1 or 0

[image: column definition]

The thing is that when I do it locally with my MariaDB database server it works fine (1 if the customer has checked the checkbox, 0 otherwise), but in production it's always saved as 0.

If I see in chrome development tools the post request in prod has newsletter 0 and newsletter 1 in the request.

[image: post request]

The problem then is the definition of the checkbox?

thanks

Comment: The checkbox is fine, in PHP you'll end up with the last value for the key, as PHP arrays cannot have duplicate indices. Your problem is somewhere on the server side. If it's a newly added field in your database, make sure that you've cleared the model/schema cache (`tmp/cache/models`).

Comment: check logs at remote server, also this `$this->request->getData()['newsletter']` would be `$this->request->getData('newsletter')`

Comment: thanks @ndm it worked! I was going nuts! can I mark your response as valid answer? thanks Salines also for suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP's ORM will only save those columns that are present in the cached schema, if you don't clear the cache after adding a new field, then the column will not be present in the generated `INSERT INTO ...` (and `UPDATE ...` for that matter) query.

You will then end up with either the default value for the column being inserted (which in your case is `0`), or you'll receive an error in case the column has no default value configured.

So whenever you make changes to your database, like adding a new column, make sure that you clear the model/schema cache afterwards, by either manually deleting the files in the temporary data folder:

```
tmp/cache/models
```

using the [**schema cache shell/command**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/console-and-shells/schema-cache.html) (database connection specific):

```
bin/cake schema_cache clear
```

or using the [**cache shell/command**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/console-and-shells/cache.html) (cache configuration specific):

```
bin/cake cache clear _cake_model_
```